# what is the difference between SQL Job and Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008, taskscheduler

what is the difference between SQL Job and Windows Task Scheduler ?

AS I can add SQL Queries in both sides ... what is the difference ??

Comment: Impossible to answer without *some* context. Besides, isn't this more suitable for serverfault.com ?

Comment: Lots. The most striking being that one requires SQL Server and the other does not. What's your actual problem, assuming you have one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLJobs operate in the context of SQLServer Agent which is a part of SQLServer,Scheduling something related to SQLServer like running a query ,maintenance tasks through SQLserver jobs is very easy..

Whereas task scheduler comes with operating system and you can also schedule tasks,but very difficult to schedule any thing related to sql server,since you have to take care of authentication and many factors

Comment: but I can add some Exec Procedures and SQL Queries in Windows Task Scheduler ... so what is the difference ?!

Comment: you can add,but you have take care of authentication,sending email and many many things..

Comment: I understood what you Said .. Thanks dear :)

Answer (score 1):

Job is basic increment any work flow and task is specific steps to complete the job, we can say job is Forrest and tree is task. and you can set job without task but not possible to set up task without job.